# How to redefine event in IE11?

Tags: javascript

I want to see 'x' alerted, instead of the original event.

```js
onclick = function() {
  window.event = 'x';
  alert(window.event);
};
```

Comment: it's probably read only

Comment: While what @self said is probably the reason , on IE11 I'm seeing `x` in the alert.

Comment: I've checked the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974340(v=vs.85).aspx), but I don't find anything regarding if it's read only. But it seems to be. @SpencerWieczorek I'm on Win10Prox64 using IE11.20.10586.0 and I see "[object PointerEvent]".

Comment: Why not alert ("x") instead

Comment: @JaromandaX This is probably just a simple example, the user want's to know why `window.event` isn't being redefined in the general case.

Comment: Perhaps it works of you assign an event object. The sample code is too abstract to provide any useful answer

Comment: @JaromandaX I think [IE doesn't support assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility). (Assignment doesn't work in this case anyway.) The sample code is abstract because the question itself is abstract too, since I'm looking for a general solution, as Spencer Wieczorek guessed.